# Replacing HTML contents with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm relatively new to Javascript, so I've pieced together the code I have by looking through the forums on here. However, I cannot get this to work, and I am needing help.

The desired end result I am trying to achieve is that whenever a user calls the `moreInfo(ID)` function, a modal pops up on the screen with the contents of the modal being populated from an external file that is built using PHP.

Right now, whenever I call the function, the modal pops up but does not display the external file. Instead, the modal displays the current page (??). A live version can be found here: http://classcolonies.com/app/test.php/

What am I doing wrong? How do I need to go about doing this instead? An explanation along with a solution would be ideal so I can learn and grow in my journey to understand javascript.

**Launch Page (used to launch the modal)**

```
<h1>Test Screen</h1><button onclick='moreInfo("12");'>Test</button>

 <div id="infoModal" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-window">
     <span id="moreInfo"></span>
   </div>
 </div>


 <script>                                                                        /* AJAX name selector */
   var infoModal = document.getElementById("infoModal");

   function moreInfo(str){
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
               document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
       }

       xmlhttp.open("GET","moreinfo.tem.php?assID=" + str, true);
       xmlhttp.send();

       infoModal.style.display = "block";                                        /* After fetching request, make modal appear */
   }

   window.onclick = function(event) {                                              /* Make modal disappear when you click "X" */
     if (event.target == infoModal) {infoModal.style.display = "none";}
   }
 </script>

 <style>
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    right: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s}

  /* Customized part listed below */

  .modal-window{
    display: grid;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px; height: 350px;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: height 0.5s;
    grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 60px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "top"
      "content"
      "controls";}

  /* --------[TOP] -------- */
  .modal-top {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: top;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5B7042;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 80px;}

  .pic{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65px;
    clip-path: circle();
    margin-left: 10px;}

  .modal-top .title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 26px}

  .due {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: gray;}


  /* --------[CONTENT] -------- */
  .modal-content {
    display: block;
    grid-area: content;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 12px;}

  .directions {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.7}

  textarea {
    display: none;
    width: 100%; height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    margin-top: 20px;}

  /* --------[CONTROLS] -------- */
  .modal-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: controls}

  #askforhelp {margin-right: 10px;}

  #sendmsg {display: none; margin-right: 10px}
  #cancelmsg {display: none}
 </style>
```

**External file, used to replace the `<span id="moreInfo">` with actual content**

```
<div class='modal-top'>
  <img class='pic' src='../resources/pics/1.png'>
  <span class='title'> Reading Homework </span>
  <span class='due'> Due 3d </span>
</div>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class='directions'>
    <b>Directions:</b> You must complete the assignment to continue to the next section. Please type complete sentences and capitalization. Let me know if you need help.
  </div>
  <textarea placeholder='Type Question..'></textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-controls">
  <button id='askforhelp' class='button green-btn' onclick='askHelp("showform")'>Ask for Help</button>
  <button id='markdone' class='button green-btn'>Mark as Done</button>
  <button id='sendmsg' class='button green-btn'>Send Message</button>
  <button id='cancelmsg' class='button grey-btn' onclick='askHelp("hideform")'>Cancel Message</button>
</div>

<script>

  function askHelp(arg) {

    var window = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-window')[0];
    var textbox = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

    var helpBtn = document.getElementById('askforhelp');
    var doneBtn = document.getElementById('markdone');
    var sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendmsg');
    var cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancelmsg');

    if (arg == "showform") {
      window.style.height = '400px';
      textbox.style.display = 'block';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'none';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'none';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'block';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }

    if (arg == "hideform") {
      window.style.height = '350px';
      textbox.style.display = 'none';
      helpBtn.style.display = 'block';
      doneBtn.style.display = 'block';
      sendBtn.style.display = 'none';
      cancelBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you verified you're getting the expected response? Is the URL correct? Any errors show up in the console?

Comment: @Phaelaxz I'm not sure how to verify I've gotten the expected response. The URL is for sure correct, you can see that live on the site as well. No errors on the console.

Comment: Buttons by default are submit buttons and submit a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by @Gil, Update your moreInfo function as below:

```
function moreInfo(str){
   fetch("moreinfo.tem.php?assID=" + str).then((res) => res.text()).then(response=>{
     document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=response;
     infoModal.style.display = "block";
    });
}
```

`fetch` returns a promise. From that promise, return the evaluated text from the response. This yields another promise which would contain the html or whatever.

It would be worth mentioning that the script in the returned html won't execute, so your askHelp function won't be defined. You can parse the html response and `inject` any script contents into the page as follow:

```
function moreInfo(str){
   infoModal.style.display = "block";
   fetch("moreinfo.tem.php?assID=" + str).then((response) =>response.text()).then((text) => {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        var ele = doc.documentElement;
        var scripts = ele.getElementsByTagName('script');
        for(var script of scripts){
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
            scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            scriptElement.innerText = script.innerText;
            head.appendChild(scriptElement);
            head.removeChild(scriptElement);
       }
       document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=text;  
      });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Sometimes it still seems to load the contents of the page (https://classcolonies.com/app/test.php) instead of the external page (https://classcolonies.com/app/moreinfo.tem.php?assID=1)

Comment: It'll happen if you access the test.php with a trailing slash (.../test.php/ ). It depends on the configuration of your server though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fetch` instead.

Something like:

```
function moreInfo(str){
   fetch("moreinfo.tem.php?assID=" + str).then((response) => {
      response.text().then((text) => {
         document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML=text;
         infoModal.style.display = "block";
      });
   })
}
```

Some explanation about the syntax here:
fetch makes an HTTP request to the URL provided (default is GET request, unless specified otherwise)
`.then` means, do something after the request is done.
`(response) => {}` is an arrow notation in JavaScript.
it's the same as writing `function(response) {...}`

Comment: I tried this, but then got an error ```[object Promise]```. You can see the error on the live link, http://classcolonies.com/app/test.php/

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to add a callback to the `text()` function - i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('xxx/com/api')
.then(responese=>responese.json())
.then(data=>{ do something..}
```

remember to add `json()` within first `.then`

Comment: How would I insert the modal code using AJAX? That is the part I am having trouble accomplishing. The modal works just fine if everything is on one page, but whenever I am trying to call an external file (IE: modal.tem.php) then things go wacky and the modal does not work.